# How to duplicate a product using Shopify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'd like to duplicate an existing Shopify product with all its images and variants.

How can I do this using the Shopify gem?

I'm running Rails 3.2.2 and the Shopify gem 3.0.1.

Thanks,
Augusto

**UPDATE # 1:**

I tried the following code:

I think the problem might be that I'm trying to create a new product with the same shopifyid as the original one.  But I'm not sure, I think there might be other issues around.

```
original_p = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(xxx)
new_p = ShopifyAPI::Product.new(original_p.attributes)
new_p.save

ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found.
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:136:in `handle_response'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shopify_api-3.0.1/lib/active_resource/connection_ext.rb:9:in `handle_response_with_response_capture'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:115:in `request'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shopify_api-3.0.1/lib/active_resource/connection_ext.rb:13:in `request_with_detailed_log_subscriber'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:92:in `block in put'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:218:in `with_auth'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:92:in `put'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1354:in `update'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/observing.rb:19:in `update_with_notifications'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1156:in `save'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/validations.rb:79:in `save_with_validation'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeresource-3.2.2/lib/active_resource/observing.rb:19:in `save_with_notifications'
from (irb):26
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.2p290 :027 > np.errors
```

Comment: I suggest you read the Shopify documentation regarding how to find a product, and how to create a product. [show a product](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#show) and [create a product](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#create)

Comment: Thanks Magicmarkker, but the Shopify API documentation shows how to create a new product using JSON.  I'd like to duplicate an existing product using the Shopify gem (Ruby).

Comment: I do not want you to write the code for me but I need some help in order to use the Shopify gem, not the Shopify JSON API.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't found a solution.

1. I would suggest first Find the product that you wish to Duplicate and save its info into say a local database (eg. Duplicate Ojbect)
2. Take your local version and then create via the API

   `product = ShopifyAPI::Product.create({ :body_html => duplicate.body_html, :title => duplicate.title })`

Where the `duplicate` is from your local: `duplicate = Duplicate.find().last` or something along those lines.